# XML not being serialised correctly into object

Tags: c#, xml, object, serialization, type-conversion

I am trying to serialise a piece of XML that is being returned from a third party API. However when doing so i am only retrieving part of the object upon serialisation. And only some of the values seem to exist. I thought this could be a input type problem, however all the types seem to be correct. I think it may have something to do with how my model is constructed.After debugging the code i have narrowed it down to be a problem with the conversion of the xml into the object.

C# CODE:

```
//[Route("api/AvailabiliyCheck/GetAvailability/{CSSDistrictCode}/{GoldAddressKey}")]
    public EADAvailabilityDetails GetAvailabilityEAD([FromUri] string CSSDistrictCode, [FromUri] string GoldAddressKey)
    {
        //Load the request xml template
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/XML/Availability/GetAvailabilityEAD.xml");
        doc.Load(path);

        //Assign incoming paramaters to xml template
        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("soap", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
        manager.AddNamespace("stupid_xmlns", "http://webservices.talktalkplc.com/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService");

        XmlNode CSSDistrictCodeNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("soap:Envelope/soap:Body/stupid_xmlns:GetAvailability/stupid_xmlns:request/stupid_xmlns:RequestDetails/stupid_xmlns:CSSDistrictCode", manager);
        CSSDistrictCodeNode.InnerXml = CSSDistrictCode;

        XmlNode GoldAddressKeyNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("soap:Envelope/soap:Body/stupid_xmlns:GetAvailability/stupid_xmlns:request/stupid_xmlns:RequestDetails/stupid_xmlns:GoldAddressKey", manager);
        GoldAddressKeyNode.InnerXml = GoldAddressKey;

        //Send Request To API    
        string _url = "https://b2b.api.talktalkgroup.com/api/v2/partners/AvailabilityCheckers/NPAC/v45";
        string _action = "http://webservices.talktalkplc.com/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService/GetAvailability";
        string xml = doc.InnerXml;

        var soapResult = WebService.ApiRequest(_url, _action, xml);

        XmlDocument xmlToFormat = new XmlDocument();
        xmlToFormat.LoadXml(soapResult);

        string Outerxml = xmlToFormat.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes[2].InnerXml;
        //Remove all namespaces
        var xmlToBeStripped = XElement.Parse(Outerxml);
        string finalXml = XmlFormatter.stripNS(xmlToBeStripped).ToString();

        EADAvailabilityDetails result;

        // Deserialises xlm into an object 

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EADAvailabilityDetails));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(finalXml))
        {
            result = (EADAvailabilityDetails)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

XML being returned:

```
 <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetAvailabilityResponse xmlns="http://webservices.talktalkplc.com/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService">
         <GetAvailabilityResult xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Status xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InHouse.SharedLibraries.ServiceBase.BaseTypes">
               <Errors/>
               <HasErrors>false</HasErrors>
            </Status>
            <CSSDistrictCode>lv</CSSDistrictCode>
            <EADAvailability>
               <AvailabilityDetails i:type="EADAvailabilityDetails">
                  <Status xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/InHouse.SharedLibraries.ServiceBase.BaseTypes">
                     <Errors/>
                     <HasErrors>false</HasErrors>
                  </Status>
                  <EADAvailability>
                     <EADAvailabilityResult>
                        <CollectorNodeExchangeCode>NDMAI</CollectorNodeExchangeCode>
                        <CollectorNodeExchangeName>Maidstone</CollectorNodeExchangeName>
                        <Distance>0</Distance>
                        <EADBandwidth xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                           <a:string>100M</a:string>
                        </EADBandwidth>
                        <EADSubType>EAD-LA</EADSubType>
                        <FibreExchangeCode>NDACO</FibreExchangeCode>
                        <FibreExchangename>Archers Court</FibreExchangename>
                        <IndicativeECC>Within tariff</IndicativeECC>
                        <IndicativeOrderCategory>Category 2.1</IndicativeOrderCategory>
                        <LocalExchangeCode>NDACO</LocalExchangeCode>
                        <LocalExchangeName>Archers Court</LocalExchangeName>
                        <ORLeadTime>40</ORLeadTime>
                        <OrderCategoryExplanation>There is a T node within 1km (or 650m in London) with spare capacity and ducting is in place, however some additional cabling is required between  the premises and the T node.</OrderCategoryExplanation>
                        <TTLeadTime>56</TTLeadTime>
                        <Zone>0</Zone>
                     </EADAvailabilityResult>
                     <EADAvailabilityResult>
                        <CollectorNodeExchangeCode>NDMAI</CollectorNodeExchangeCode>
                        <CollectorNodeExchangeName>Maidstone</CollectorNodeExchangeName>
                        <Distance>0</Distance>
                        <EADBandwidth xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                           <a:string>LOW 1GB</a:string>
                        </EADBandwidth>
                        <EADSubType>EAD-LA</EADSubType>
                        <FibreExchangeCode>NDACO</FibreExchangeCode>
                        <FibreExchangename>Archers Court</FibreExchangename>
                        <IndicativeECC>Within tariff</IndicativeECC>
                        <IndicativeOrderCategory>Category 2.1</IndicativeOrderCategory>
                        <LocalExchangeCode>NDACO</LocalExchangeCode>
                        <LocalExchangeName>Archers Court</LocalExchangeName>
                        <ORLeadTime>40</ORLeadTime>
                        <OrderCategoryExplanation>There is a T node within 1km (or 650m in London) with spare capacity and ducting is in place, however some additional cabling is required between  the premises and the T node.</OrderCategoryExplanation>
                        <TTLeadTime>56</TTLeadTime>
                        <Zone>0</Zone>
                     </EADAvailabilityResult>
                     <EADAvailabilityResult>
                        <CollectorNodeExchangeCode>NDCAN</CollectorNodeExchangeCode>
                        <CollectorNodeExchangeName>Canterbury</CollectorNodeExchangeName>
                        <Distance>20656</Distance>
                        <EADBandwidth xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
                           <a:string>HIGH 1GB</a:string>
                        </EADBandwidth>
                        <EADSubType>EAD-NonLA</EADSubType>
                        <FibreExchangeCode>NDCAN</FibreExchangeCode>
                        <FibreExchangename>Canterbury</FibreExchangename>
                        <IndicativeECC>Within tariff</IndicativeECC>
                        <IndicativeOrderCategory>Category 2.1</IndicativeOrderCategory>
                        <LocalExchangeCode>NDACO</LocalExchangeCode>
                        <LocalExchangeName>Archers Court</LocalExchangeName>
                        <ORLeadTime>40</ORLeadTime>
                        <OrderCategoryExplanation>There is a T node within 1km (or 650m in London) with spare capacity and ducting is in place, however some additional cabling is required between  the premises and the T node.</OrderCategoryExplanation>
                        <TTLeadTime>56</TTLeadTime>
                        <Zone>B</Zone>
                     </EADAvailabilityResult>
                  </EADAvailability>
                  <LeadTime>10</LeadTime>
               </AvailabilityDetails>
            </EADAvailability>
            <GoldAddressKey>A00009292752</GoldAddressKey>
            <Postcode/>
         </GetAvailabilityResult>
      </GetAvailabilityResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Model:

```
 [Serializable, XmlRoot("AvailabilityDetails")]
public class EADAvailabilityDetails
{
    [XmlElement("EADAvailability")]
    public EADAvailability EADAvailability { get; set; }
}

public class EADAvailability
{
    [XmlElement("EADAvailabilityResult")]
    public List<EADAvailabilityResult> EADAvailabilityResult { get; set; }
}

public class EADAvailabilityResult
{
    [XmlElement("CollectorNodeExchangeCode")]
    public string CollectorNodeExchangeCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("CollectorNodeExchangeName")]
    public string CollectorNodeExchangeName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Distance")]
    public int Distance { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("EADBandwidth")]
    public string EADBandwidth { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("EADSubType")]
    public string EADSubType { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FibreExchangeCode")]
    public string FibreExchangeCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FibreExchangename")]
    public string FibreExchangename { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IndicativeECC")]
    public string IndicativeECC { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("IndicativeOrderCategory")]
    public string IndicativeOrderCategory { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LocalExchangeCode")]
    public string LocalExchangeCode { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("LocalExchangeName")]
    public string LocalExchangeName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("ORLeadTime")]
    public int ORLeadTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("OrderCategoryExplanation")]
    public string OrderCategoryExplanation { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TTLeadTime")]
    public int TTLeadTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Zone")]
    public int Zone { get; set; }
}
```

XML after serialisation:

```
{
"<EADAvailability>k__BackingField": {
    "EADAvailabilityResult": [
        {
            "CollectorNodeExchangeCode": "NDMAI",
            "CollectorNodeExchangeName": "Maidstone",
            "Distance": 0,
            "EADBandwidth": "100M",
            "EADSubType": null,
            "FibreExchangeCode": null,
            "FibreExchangename": null,
            "IndicativeECC": null,
            "IndicativeOrderCategory": null,
            "LocalExchangeCode": null,
            "LocalExchangeName": null,
            "ORLeadTime": 0,
            "OrderCategoryExplanation": null,
            "TTLeadTime": 0,
            "Zone": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: The "XML after serialisation" is in fact JSON.  Does the JSON represent what you have managed to deserialize from the xml?

Comment: Can you show the part of your code which produces the "XML after serialization"?

Comment: I am only after the properties within the "EADAvailability" node. Which i have listed in my model. The problem is that only some of the properties are being returned with values in them and some are being returned as null, when they shouldn't be. The other issue is only one "EADAvailabilityResult" node is being serialised when in fact there is two.

Comment: Hey ed that part of the code is in the "C# CODE:" section just before the return statement.

Comment: @ashleyg Please indicate what part of that code generates the JSON string you pasted in as "XML after serialization". You never serialize anything in that code. Is the JSON in the variable named `path`? Is the JSON in the variable named `xml`?  Is it in `soapResult`, `Outerxml`? Where did you get the JSON from? Please show me the exact line of code where you got the JSON from.

Comment: The response XML is in the soapResult variable. The OuterXml then only takes part of the response XML what i am interested in starting with the root node being "AvailabilityDetails". Then the Namespaces are stripped before the deserialisation takes place using the final Xml variable. The "XML after serialization" code, is produced by sending a POST request to my API through Postman.

Comment: @ashleyg You have a block of JSON text in your question labeled "XML after serialisation". Do you have any memory, any recollection at all, of where you found that text? Do you have any memory of why you added it to your question? Did one of your friends send it to you in an email or a text message? Did you find it written on a napkin an a bar?

Comment: :O that is what is being produced after sending a request to this method using an api tester. 
EADAvailabilityDetails result;
        // Deserialises xlm into an object 

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EADAvailabilityDetails));
        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(finalXml))
        {
            result = (EADAvailabilityDetails)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below works :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace ConsoleApplication139
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));

            Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement (Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
        public Body Body { get; set; }
    }
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://webservices.talktalkplc.com/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService")]
        public GetAvailabilityResponse GetAvailabilityResponse { get; set; }
    }
    public class GetAvailabilityResponse
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "http://webservices.talktalkplc.com/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService")]
        public GetAvailabilityResult GetAvailabilityResult { get; set; }
    }
    public class GetAvailabilityResult
    {
        [XmlArray("EADAvailability", Namespace = "http://webservices.talktalkplc.com/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService")]
        [XmlArrayItem("AvailabilityDetails", Namespace = "http://webservices.talktalkplc.com/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService")]
        public AvailabilityDetails[] AvailabilityDetails { get; set; }
    }
    [XmlInclude(typeof(EADAvailabilityDetails))]
    [Serializable, XmlRoot("AvailabilityDetails", Namespace = "http://webservices.talktalkplc.com/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService")]
    public class AvailabilityDetails
    {
    }
    [Serializable, XmlRoot("EADAvailabilityDetails", Namespace = "http://webservices.talktalkplc.com/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService")]
    public class EADAvailabilityDetails : AvailabilityDetails
    {
        [XmlArray("EADAvailability", Namespace = "http://webservices.talktalkplc.com/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService")]
        [XmlArrayItem("EADAvailabilityResult", Namespace = "http://webservices.talktalkplc.com/NetworkProductAvailabilityCheckerService")]
        public EADAvailabilityResult[] EADAvailabilityResult { get; set; }
    }
    public class EADAvailabilityResult
    {
        public string CollectorNodeExchangeCode { get; set; }
        public string CollectorNodeExchangeName { get; set; }
        public int Distance { get; set; }
        public EADBandwidth EADBandwidth { get; set; }
        public string EADSubType { get; set; }
        public string FibreExchangeCode { get; set; }
        public string FibreExchangename { get; set; }
        public string IndicativeECC { get; set; }
        public string IndicativeOrderCategory { get; set; }
        public string LocalExchangeCode { get; set; }
        public string LocalExchangeName { get; set; }
        public int ORLeadTime { get; set; }
        public string OrderCategoryExplanation { get; set; }
        public int TTLeadTime { get; set; }
        public string Zone { get; set; }
    }
    public class EADBandwidth
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "string", Type = typeof(string), Namespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays")]
        public string String { get; set; }
    }







}
```